# Does Scalar Field imply it is time-invarant

Tags: field-theory, scalar-fields

I am writing an article on data acquisition pertaining to  terrain mapping. I want to know if I can collectively call mapping of such static surfaces,  scalar fields? So in otherwords does stating them as scalar field imply that they dont change over time or time-invariant? Since, Vector field on the other hand imply change, by the very definition of the "magnitude" & "direction". So does stating scalar field imply the it is time invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar is just one element of a field. Thus, a scalar function is a function that takes as argument only one element of that field. Obviously, time is a scalar, and a function that only depends on time is also a scalar function. Nothing to do with time-invariance.

Don't mix up spacetime invariances with a function being vector- or scalar- valued. A vector function can also be rotational or translational invariant. It doesn't have to 'change' (e.g. constant vector field).

Comment: Height above or below sea level at single point on a terrain map is directed approximately vertically up or down and is a vector. Think of plate tectonics and there are horizontal, vertical and arbitrarily directed relative velocities associated with the roughly spherical earths crust of the order cm/year

Comment: @JamesArathoon And we care because..?

Comment: For example if the Caldera volcano under Yellowstone National Park starts causing abnormal terrain movements (bulging up quickly) then it might be time to emigrate from North America. The OP hasn't said what they are mapping, it could be the land surrounding a volcano or a long dormant Caldera.

Comment: @JamesArathoon is that even relevant for Math.SE?

Comment: @ares noted, so in short I cant generalize in the article the static surface points as scalar field. Eventhought they are scalar but the context is that they are static as well.

Comment: @JamesArathoon, true, I know what you mean to say, that they are not static. But currently I am simply referring to them as static scalar fields.